# Threshold dense adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I have a dense, adjacency matrix (square, symmetric) representing a graph. I want to threshold that graph so that it only contains the largest weights (cells in the matrix), but is still fully connected. Do you know of any fast algorithms?

Comment: I am really sad to say that I have seen the movie Zardoz in all its Sean Connery glory :P

Comment: Are you familiar with Kruskal's algorithm for finding a minimal weight spanning tree in a graph? Maybe you could adapt it by list the edges from highest weight to lowest (instead of the other way around, as is done in Kruskal) and then adding edges one at a time until what you have is connected.